# Rails3 installing Jquery plugins disables javascript altogether

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, assets

I'm running Rails 3.2.13 with RVM.
Each time I want to install a new Jquery plugin (I just tried Tablesorter http://tablesorter.com/ ) all my javascript is suddenly frozen, and the other plugins that used to work (miraculously, it sometimes ends up doing so, by some magic...) are then disabled and when I uninstall the last culprit and all its elements, they still don't work anymore, sending me back to stone-age each-time...

here is my application.js:

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery-ui
    //= require_tree .
    //= require jquery.ui.datepicker-fr
    //= require best_in_place
```

I had managed to eventually have date_picker and best_in_place work at the same time. But now that I have installed and uninstalled Tablesorter, neither of them works anymore...

It is extremely frustrating. After numerous readings, I think it has to do with either the assets pipeline (which makes an absolute mess of my public/assets folder...) or with RVM caching of assets...
I have in application.rb:

```
     config.assets.enabled = true
```

I set that because I use Heroku in production, so I need the assets to be compiled there.

I read many questions and answers relating to this assets pipeline mess, but most were either too complex for me to comprehend, or the people who wrote them supposed that readers were already experts when they aren't, and didn't go into enough details in simple words, or the context didn't apply to my case, either because they related to a rails version prior to mine or they didn't use Heroku and simply suggested to disable the assets pipeline, which is needed there...

Could someone knowledgeable enough please take a few minutes to explain, in simple words and detailed actions to be undertaken, what is going on and what I should do ?
I think I must not be the only one undergoing this ordeal.

I would greatly appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `//= require_tree .` at the last.

You calls to the plugins should be placed at the last.

Comment: Thank you for you most timely, concise and effective answer!
That works, in effect.
But I don't understand what's going on in this.
Do I need to do a "rake assets:precompile" everytime I add a plugin? And what shall I do when I remove one?

Comment: @cedric, if in development, you don't need to precompile assets. Just require the js files names and you are fine. Showing all js files in source helps you debugging. Sometimes you may need to restart development server if new file not showing.