# Rails3: additional jQuery gems don't work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm, asset-pipeline

I'm experiencing the following problem:

I operate rails 3.2.13 with RVM and I have installed 3 Jquery gems which ended up working, somehow (although they didn't initially, and I haven't understood why they suddenly started to work...): Datepicker, BestInPlace and DataTables.

Now, whenever I install additional Jquery gems, they never work. I tried everything, to no avail. It's like their code is frozen, although I have painstakingly followed each of their installation instructions: application.js //=require ... / application.css *= require ...proper coffee script functions...

I need a color picker and I tried 4 different ones: jPicker, Colorpicker, Minicolors, Farbstatic => none of them worked.

Eventually, the last installation and subsequent de-installation of Farbstatic somehow interfered with my Datatables which don't work anymore, although I have uninstalled the gem and all its elements...This is so confusing!

I've got the feeling that some caching issue is taking place here, since the first 3 gems started working almost miraculously after painstaking efforts, without apparent reason, after so many failures...but this is beyond me.

I'm working with assets pipeline and I was wondering whether that could have a role in this bizarre malfunctioning as well, maybe together with RVM...I don't know. I'm lost.

Any helping direction would be most welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails3 installing Jquery plugins disables javascript altogether](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443708/rails3-installing-jquery-plugins-disables-javascript-altogether)

Comment: no it's not a duplicate, because I now systematically place  //= require_tree . at the last place. I believed that had solved the problem with an earlier gem, but it was probably a coincidence, because all the other jquery gems I have installed since, respecting this instruction, don't work anyway.

Comment: Ever more bizarre : Farbtastic doesn't work on my local machine (OSX 10.7.5) but does on Heroku...

Comment: now this is maddening: datepicker and bestinplace work on my local machine, but farbtastic doesn't and on Heroku, this is just the reverse...go figure out!